# How do I symlink binaries under /usr/local/util to the default searchable /bin?

Tags: linux, bash

There are multiple binaries under `/usr/local/util` so I don't want to do it by running `ln -s /bin/util_i /usr/local/util/util_i` multiple times.

Anyway,what I want to achieve is that I don't need to type `/usr/local/util/` to run binaries under it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't copy into `/bin` if you can help it.

```
cp -sn /usr/local/util/* /usr/local/bin
```

But what you *should* be doing is adding `/usr/local/util` to `$PATH`.

Comment: How can I add `/usr/local/util` to `$PATH` in linux?

Comment: Depends on the shell. For bash look in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: I modified `.bash_profile` this way but doesn't work: `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/usr/local/subversion/bin`.Do I need to run some command to notify bash to refresh the settings?

Comment: `~/.bash_profile` is read when logging in.

Comment: Oh thanks!What's the difference of `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` ?

Comment: `~/.bash_profile` is run when bash is run on login. `~/.bashrc` is run when bash is run as an interactive shell.

Comment: non-interactive shell is like cron jobs,right?

Comment: As the interpreter for a script. Which cron jobs can fall under.

Answer (score 0):

why not add this path to `$PATH` in `/etc/profile`

according to this [link](http://stefaanlippens.net/bashrc_and_others), the sequence of configuration files is

- /etc/profile
- ~/.bash_profile
- ~/.bash_login
- ~/.profile